# how to optimize this piece of JS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry JS newbie here:

```
    if (message.notify_one_day_out){
        $("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]").val("1");
    }
    else{
        $("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]").val("0");
    }
```

The above code feels sloppy. How can I condense it? I know this is development fundamentals but can I do something like:

```
$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]").val(message.notify_one_day_out);
```

Comment: What does mean \\ in js selector?

Comment: whenever you have brackets as an id name, you have to escape them else jQuery does not recognize it.

Comment: It's not the fact that your code is not condensed, but the fact that there's enough backslashes in there for a year's usage... I'd start there.

Comment: @AronRotteveel: And how would he solve that?

Comment: @jgauffin did some extra research and noticed HTML5 allows anything but spaces now. Previous statement was made under the assumption of the pre-HTML5 spec, which would render this HTML invalid. Even so, assuming the author has control over the HTML, I would opt for underscores, dashes, or anything but brackets.

Comment: @jini jQuery uses CSS selectors for determining elements. using `[]` means its looking at the attribute. like when i have `$('a[href="index]')` - it looks for an anchor with href that has the value "index". that's why it wont work.

Comment: i suggest you turn those `[]` into dashes or underscores. that way it won't be that messy

Answer (score 5):

```
//this is actually a function call "$()" better reference it to avoid overhead
var el = $("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]");

el.val( message.notify_one_day_out ? '1' : '0');
```

i suggest you turn those `[]` into dashes or underscores. that way it won't be that messy.

Comment: yes, do your selectors once at the top and don't keep calling the $(...) function for the same selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]").val(
               message.notify_one_day_out ? "1" : "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator (also called *conditional operator*):

```
$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]").val(
         message.notify_one_day_out ? '1' : '0' );
```

Here is prototype of ternary operator:

```
(expression) ? this if true : this if false;
```

Essentially it is shorthand of `if-else` statements.

---

You can read more about it here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

```
$("#data\\[User\\]\\[notify_one_day_out\\]").val(message.notify_one_day_out ? "1" : "0");
```